# MySQL select in subquery retrive one or more data record as a set

Tags: mysql

Assume 2 table like this:

```
> [persons]                 [groups]
> id | name                id | member
> ---+-------              ---+-------
> 1  | anna                1  | 1,3,4
> 2  | jake                2  | 2,4,5
> 3  | jhon                3  | 1,2,3
> 4  | jessica             4  | 4,5
> 5  | albert              5  | 1,6,7
```

I try to get members of group id 2 and 3 using

```
select id,name from persons 
               where id in (select member from groups where id in (2,3));
```

but only one record (id=2) is returned. Any suggestion?

Comment: your groups table is having a varchar in member field??
You should separate this into 3 tables, with third one mapping group_id to person_id

Comment: @ hyades, you are right. member is a varchar field. but i try to do it with minimum change on data structure. i can plan a one to many person>group or group>person. but prefer to keep the structure unchange. any other idea?

Comment: Following normalisation is a good thing because it eliminates such issues.

Comment: At present, your data has no structure. So don't worry about changing anything.

Comment: @Strawberry, it's a simple sample of real. i try your 'hint' if i can't do any more. but  'group_concat' seems can do what i need. although, group_concat return an string not a set.

Comment: take the time to restructure your data, it will save you more time than it costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your goal is, but just my guess:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6942/3

```
SELECT DISTINCT persons.id, persons.name
FROM persons
INNER JOIN groups
ON  FIND_IN_SET(persons.id,groups.member)>0
   AND groups.id IN (2,3)
```

And I agree with @hyades you should better redesign your database.